# Model forn not rendering

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-views, django-templates

I made a model for downloadable files. I can create them through the admin just fine. However, when I try to load my upload form no fields appear. I believe this is exactly how I render all my other forms.

**template.html**

```
   {% load crispy_forms_tags %}

   <form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST">
      {% csrf_token %}
      {{form|crispy}}
      {{form.errors}}
      <button type="submit" class="btn submit-btn mt-3 mr-2"><i class="fa fa-share"></i> Submit</button>
    </form>
```

**forms.py**

```
from django import forms
from .models import DownloadableFile


class DownloadableFileForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = DownloadableFile
        fields = '__all__'
```

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.

class DownloadableFile(models.Model):
    CHOICES = (
        ('MARKETING MATERIAL - (FORMS)', 'MARKETING MATERIAL - (FORMS)'),
        ('MARKETING MATERIAL - (LOGOS & IMAGES)', 'MARKETING MATERIAL - (LOGOS & IMAGES)'),
        ('OTHER DOCUMENTS & FORMS', 'OTHER DOCUMENTS & FORMS'),
    )

    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    file_type = models.CharField(max_length=255, choices=CHOICES)
    description = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    upload_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    file = models.FileField(upload_to='downloads/')

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "Downloadable Files"

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

**views.py**

```
@login_required
def create_downloadable_file_view(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = DownloadableFileForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            form = form.save()
            return redirect('main:homepage_view')
    else:
        form = DownloadableFileForm
    context = {
        'files': DownloadableFile.objects.all(),
    }
    return render(request=request, template_name="dashboard/create-file.html", context=context)


def delete_downloadable_file_view(request, pk):
    obj = get_object_or_404(DownloadableFile, pk=pk)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        obj.delete()
        return redirect('dashboard:dashboard_view')
```

Comment: Your `context` doesn't contain your form

Comment: Ugh I'm disgusting... Thank you